# Drupal 7 fresh installation access denied user one

Tags: php, drupal-7

Ok after installing Drupal 7 i have got following issue:

When i visited my site and typed proper username and password for user one i couldn't log in.

I've checked session table and found a row with uid 0. When I deleted it and tried to log in I logged in (yeah success!). But when I logged out and tried to log in again I get access denied again. Session table got row with uid 0 again (I suppose that is correct).

I've checked my user table and figured out that I've got 2 rows: uid: 0 and uid: 1, when I deleted user 0 I could log in as user one each time and all was working fine. But I've already read that Drupal uses uid 0 for anonymous user so I can't delete it.

I've tried to set proper `$cookie_domain` in settings.php but it doesn't help.
Still the same issue. What can it be? Drupal's Masters please help.

I have `session.cookie_secure` off. My app is running on xampp with PHP 5.6.3 on Windows 7. Drupal version 7.34, database MySql 5.6.21, and they say in docs PHP for drupal 7 PHP 5.2.5 * (5.4 or higher recommended), so i suppose it should work with PHP 5.6.3

Regards

### Edit

After each log in attempt in session table there is new row with uid 0, so after 5 attempt i've got 5 sessions with uid 0 and ssid null

Comment: Don't be disappointed if no one helps; this installation specific question is probably too far away and too open for this forum.

Comment: @peter_the_oak yeah i understand but maybe someone had this issue and can help :)

Comment: uid 0 is the anonymous user, right? uid1 is your admin user? so when you log in with your admin user, it shouldn't create a session entry for uid 0. This doesn't sound correct.

What happens when you log in with admin, then open up a new incognito tab and try to log in again?

Comment: @dustinmoris the issue is that i cannot login as admin, when im doing it there is access denied and new row in sessions is created with uid 0. I can only log in as Admin when i load site and clear sesssions table or when i delete user 0 (Anonymous user). But both solutions are unacceptable.

Comment: I understand, but you can log in the first time right, so following attemps fail. I am asking to try it out in an incognito window to check if it is cookie related or not.

Comment: @dustinmoris yes i've tryied and failed, and no, first login wasn't succesfull.  First successful login i achieved when i loaded site again, cleared session table and without reloading site logged in. If i reload site after clearing session table, the new row with uid 0 appears and I cannot log in.

Comment: is it a completely fresh install with no additional modules yet? which db are you using? which D7 version did you install?  Are you sure that D7 works properly on PHP 5.6? The docs don't convince me: https://www.drupal.org/requirements/php

Comment: @dustinmoris, yes it's a fresh install drupal 7.34, database MySql 5.6.21, and they say in docs PHP for drupal 7 PHP 5.2.5 * (5.4 or higher recommended), so i suppose it should work with 5.6.3